# Formatting in FPDF library in PHP

Tags: php, pdf, fpdf

I am using FPDF library in PHP to generated PDFs. Please consider my following code which generates a PDF:

```
<?php
require("fpdf181/fpdf.php");
class PDF extends FPDF
{
    //Page header
    function Header()
    {

    }

    //Page footer
    function Footer()
    {

    }

}
$pdf = new PDF('P', 'mm', 'A4');
$pdf->AliasNbPages();
$pdf->AddPage();

$pdf->SetFont('Arial','U',14);
$pdf->MultiCell(90, 8, "Student Details", 0, 'L');

$pdf->SetFont('Arial','B',12);
$pdf->Cell(32, 8, "Username: ");
$pdf->SetFont('Arial','',12);
$pdf->Cell(10, 8, 'abc123', 0, 1);

$pdf->SetFont('Arial','B',12);
$pdf->Cell(32, 8, "Name: ");
$pdf->SetFont('Arial','',12);
$pdf->Cell(10, 8, 'John', 0, 1);

$pdf->SetFont('Arial','U',14);
$pdf->MultiCell(90, 8, "Parent Details", 0, 'L');

$pdf->SetFont('Arial','B',12);
$pdf->Cell(32, 8, "Name: ");
$pdf->SetFont('Arial','',12);
$pdf->Cell(10, 8, 'Mathew', 0, 1);

$pdf->SetFont('Arial','B',12);
$pdf->Cell(32, 8, "Occupation: ");
$pdf->SetFont('Arial','',12);
$pdf->Cell(10, 8, 'Businessman', 0, 1);

$pdf->Output();

?>
```

Now it generates a PDF which looks like this:

```
Student Details
Username: abc123
Name: John
Parent Details
Name: Mathew
Occupation: Businessman
```

But I need output like this:

```
Student Details            Parent Details
Username: abc123           Name: Mathew
Name: John                 Occupation: Businessman
```

What changes should I make in my code to achieve this kind of formatting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place your cells horizontally not vertically. Consider your page is 210mm wide, you may write:

```
<?php
require("fpdf181/fpdf.php");
$pdf = new FPDF('P', 'mm', 'A4');
$pdf->AliasNbPages();
$pdf->AddPage();

$pdf->SetFont('Arial','U',14);
$pdf->Cell(90, 8, "Student Details", 0, 'L');
$pdf->Cell(90, 8, "Parent Details", 0, 'L');

$pdf->Ln();

$pdf->SetFont('Arial','B',12);
$pdf->Cell(35, 8, "Username: ");
$pdf->SetFont('Arial','',12);
$pdf->Cell(55, 8, 'abc123', 0);

$pdf->SetFont('Arial','B',12);
$pdf->Cell(35, 8, "Name: ");
$pdf->SetFont('Arial','',12);
$pdf->Cell(55, 8, 'Mathew', 0);

$pdf->Ln();

$pdf->Output();
```

Comment: This is the simple approach, I think. I am doing the same instead of creating complex tables which will delay loading the PDF. Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

TO achieve that you can use table method. Find working example here : http://www.fpdf.org/en/tutorial/tuto5.htm

Or try Simply this : (http://www.fpdf.org/en/script/script50.php)

```
<?php
    require('html_table.php');

    $pdf=new PDF();
    $pdf->AddPage();
    $pdf->SetFont('Arial','',12);

    $html='<table border="0">
        <tr>
            <td width="200" height="30">cell 1</td><td width="200" height="30" bgcolor="#D0D0FF">cell 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td width="200" height="30">cell 3</td><td width="200" height="30">cell 4</td>
        </tr>
    </table>';

    $pdf->WriteHTML($html);
    $pdf->Output();
?>
```

Comment: what is the path of html_table.php?

Comment: @KPJoy - it is a file to direct support tables for fpdf something like extension. You can download it from bottom of the page with example from this link : http://www.fpdf.org/en/script/script50.php